# Why does x86 jump to a new address starting from the PC pointer's tail instead of the header's address?

Tags: function, assembly, x86, system-calls, instruction-set

**in x86 **why call or jump to another** addr is start calucate** from now`s pc pointer`s tail`s address notfrom header`s address? maybe x86 has instruction prefixs？ can somebody tell me please？

the reason or some manpage like doc?

Comment: It's really just a design decision.  There's no inherent reason it couldn't have been done the other way, though I suspect doing it this way makes the hardware slightly simpler. x86 does have instruction prefixes but they don't really have anything to do with this.

Comment: "The documentation" is the [x86 Software Developer's Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html), though its purpose is just to define how the system behaves, and not to explain the reasons for the design.  (But sometimes they can be inferred.)

Comment: For future reference, the apostrophe is `'` not `\`` (backtick).  As you can see, the backtick is used in markdown to get a "code" font.